# When to decide to read next character in StreamReader from serial port device to avoid to get Timeour Error (C#)

Tags: c#, serial-port, streamreader

I send a reset connection command to a device in serial port. And In response to that i sometimes (most of the time) get a one character answer. So I use reader.Read comment after writing the first command using a streamwriter. But sometimes our device does not send a response to this first request. It is not matter for me cause i don't use the response in my software. I will just go on sending the next commands to the device. When the device does not send a response my reader.Read call gets a timeout exception and i can not go on communicating with the device. Since i don't know when the device will answer the request or not what can i do? I can either not read the first answer. But in that case the one character spoils the the following messages that the device will send me. It will be in the beginning of the message. If i use reader.read i can get timeout exception. 
I tried

```
if (reader.Peek() >= 0)
   reader.Read();
```

But it didn't help me. That time Peek() method can get timeout exception. 
How will i know if there is a character for me, or if i have to skip reading and continue to writing the next command??

Thank you for your answers,
Ferda Ozdemir

Answer (score 0):

May be just catch the exception and iterate once again by sending the packet to the device for a response. Thats what most device drivers do. May be you limit the number of retries you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method that responds to SerialPort.DataReceived event you may try something like this in it:

```
while (port.BytesToRead > 0)
{
    reader.Read(); //Or reader.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Further info on DataReceived event: [MSDN on DataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx)

Comment: Sometimes the device is not connected to serialport in stead it is connected to via ETH modem or gprs modem so i am using TCPclient in that condition. I checked there is no method for tcpclient like BytesToRead. But your suggestion can be helpfull for me for serialport connections. thank you